# MySQL query that fills specified rows with entity ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables in my MySQL database:

**DisplayArticles**

```
Id
CategoryId
ArticleId
IsAuto
```

**Articles**

```
Id
CategoryId
Title
```

Now what I need to do is to write MySQL query that will fill all positions where IsAuto set to true with newest articles from specified category (with the newest one on top position).

For example if I will have articles:

```
...

53 2 'Article that is older'
54 2 'Article about something funny'
55 6 'Article about something else'
56 2 'Article about something interesting'
```

And my display articles like:

```
1  2  12 false
2  2  42 true
3  2  41 true
4  2  23 false
5  2  25 false
```

Query invoked with with a parameter CategoryId = 2 should modify DisplayArticles table like this:

```
1  2  12 false
2  2  56 true
3  2  54 true
4  2  23 false
5  2  25 false
```

Hope this is clear and understandable. 
Please help me to write this query.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Nop, I didn't understand it fully. What do you want to do?

Comment: As I wrote: I need to write a query that will put newest article id's into DisplayArticles table but only on positions that are marked as IsAuto. Exactly as in the example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should do it.

The gist of it goes like this

- Use a subselect matching on `CategoryID`
- Select the latest `ArticleID` from `Articles` in this subselect excluding `ArticleID`'s  that are already assigned
- Add a `WHERE` clause only updating where `IsAuto` equals `true`.

**Update statement**

```
UPDATE DisplayArticles
SET    ArticleID = (SELECT MAX(ArticleID) 
                    FROM   Articles AS a                        
                    WHERE  a.CategoryID = CategoryID
                           AND ArticleID NOT IN (
                             SELECT ArticleID 
                             FROM   DisplayArticles da
                             WHERE  da.CategoryID = CategoryID 
                           )
                   )
WHERE  IsAuto = 'true'
```

Comment: It should fill it with the whole range of newest articles.. so for example if there are newest articles with ids 55 and 56 and two rows with isAuto = true, then one of them should get 55 and the second 56... Any ideas?

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl - I have altered the statement, could you verify it?

Comment: Now it have some serious chance to work fine.. I'll test it and approve it then.. thanks..